# How can I use Beautifulsoup to cleanly parse out all bullets and sub-bullets from a HTML list?

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a document that looks like this

**HEADER1**

- The virus killed 56 people
- Global press highlights hundreds of dogs jumping

  - A Twitter user posts photos of cats

**HEADER2**

- President Biden talks on Sunday.
- Hello World
- How can I help you?

**Header 3**

- The war in Gaza continues
- Global press highlights best pizza

  - A Twitter user posts sushi
  - A Twitter user posts candy

I convert it to HTML and it looks like this

```
<html>
 <body>
 <h1>HEADER1</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    the virus killed 56
   </li>
   <li>
    Global press
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
     highlight
    </a>
    hundreds of dogs jumping
    <ul>
     <li>
      A Twitter user
      <a href="http://example.com/xad/status/sda">
       posts
      </a>
      photos of cats
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 <h1>HEADER2</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    President Biden talks on Sunday.
   </li>
   Hello World
   <li>
    How can I help you?
   </li>
  </ul>
 <h1>HEADER3</h1>
 <ul>
   <li>
    The war in Gaza continues
   </li>
   <li>
    Global press highlights best pizza
    <ul>
     <li>
      A Twitter user posts sushi
     </li>
     <li>
      A Twitter user posts candy
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Because of the way the bullets are nested in lists and the the lists are themselves list objects  I can't figure out for the life of me how I can parse out each individual <li>...</li> tag that's in either the outer ul tag or the inner ul tag.

My desired end result looks something like

header1_posts = [<li>the virus killed 56</li>, <li>Global pres
s<a href="https://www.example.com">highlight</a>hundreds of dogs jumping</li>, <li>A Twitter user<a href="http://example.com/xad/status/sda">posts</a>photos of cats</li>]

header2_posts = [...]

header3_posts = [...]

I've tried all combinations of find, find_all, find_all_next and iterating through different elements, but no luck on my end.

Thanks

Comment: Questions should provide a [mcve] so please add your python code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<html>
 <body>
 <h1>HEADER1</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    the virus killed 56
   </li>
   <li>
    Global press
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
     highlight
    </a>
    hundreds of dogs jumping
    <ul>
     <li>
      A Twitter user
      <a href="http://example.com/xad/status/sda">
       posts
      </a>
      photos of cats
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 <h1>HEADER2</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    President Biden talks on Sunday.
   </li>
   Hello World
   <li>
    How can I help you?
   </li>
  </ul>
 <h1>HEADER3</h1>
 <ul>
   <li>
    The war in Gaza continues
   </li>
   <li>
    Global press highlights best pizza
    <ul>
     <li>
      A Twitter user posts sushi
     </li>
     <li>
      A Twitter user posts candy
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


def get_li_without_ul(li):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(li), "html.parser")
    for ul in soup.find_all("ul"):
        ul.extract()
    return soup


out = {}
for li in soup.find_all("li"):
    header = li.find_previous("h1")
    out.setdefault(header.text.strip(), []).append(get_li_without_ul(li))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'HEADER1': [<li>
    the virus killed 56
   </li>, <li>
    Global press
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
     highlight
    </a>
    hundreds of dogs jumping
    
</li>, <li>
      A Twitter user
      <a href="http://example.com/xad/status/sda">
       posts
      </a>
      photos of cats
     </li>], 'HEADER2': [<li>
    President Biden talks on Sunday.
   </li>, <li>
    How can I help you?
   </li>], 'HEADER3': [<li>
    The war in Gaza continues
   </li>, <li>
    Global press highlights best pizza
    
</li>, <li>
      A Twitter user posts sushi
     </li>, <li>
      A Twitter user posts candy
     </li>]}
```